# php and newlines: what I need to know?

Tags: php, mysql, cross-browser, cross-platform, newline

I have some questions about `\r\n`:

- newlines are browser dependent? (not how they are displayed in a browser, but how `<textarea>` sends them to php via http request)
- newlines are system dependent? (where php runs)
- will php apply some implicit conversion?
- will mysql apply some implicit conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question.  I would add:  What are some typical "gotchas"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- newlines are browser dependent?

  - No. Use `<br>` to get a newline in a browser
- newlines are system dependent? (where php runs)

  - yes : `\n` on OSX, `\n` on Unix/Linux, `\r\n` on Windows
- will php apply some implicit conversion?

  - no
- will mysql apply some implicit conversion?

  - no

Comment: `\r` on OSX is not the case. It was `\r` on Mac OSes prior to OSX, but OSX is BSD-based and uses `\n`. Popular misconception.

Comment: the mine was not a tricky question, but: I'm developing on windows and in mysql I have only `\n` instead of `\r\n` as you said... so what is happened here? (I have edited my question btw)

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer Almost all programs on almost all ASCII based OSes can cope transparently with `\n` or `\r\n`. Support for `\r` is not *as* wide, but is generally OK with commonly used applications. A couple of notable exceptions: notepad.exe on Windoze, and some vi/vim implementations on *nix (e.g. older busybox binaries)

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer [Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, for browser `\r` and `\n` are whitespace chars, like `' '` (whitespace) of `\t` (tab). Inside some tags (script, pre etc.) they are treated as line break symbols. In this case browser will understand any of common line break sequences (`\r`, `\r\n`, `\n`).

When data comes from textarea, line breaks will [always](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/chrismay/entry/how_are_newlines/) be represented as `\r\n`.

Line breaks in php files doesn't depend on system where they're running. It depends on settings of file editor used for creating php files. When you copy a php file to another system, line breaks format will not change.

For example, look at this code:

```
print_r("
" === "\r\n");
```

Its result will depend on settings of the editor used for creating this file. It doesn't depend on current system.

But if you're trying to read some other files contained by your system (text files, for example) these files will most probably use system's common line breaks format.

No, PHP and MySQL don't apply implicit conversions.

Comment: `Its result will depend on settings of the editor used for creating this file. It doesn't depend on current system.` - true, but only up to a point. If the file was transferred to another server in FTP ASCII mode (`TYPE A`) at some point, the behaviour may change. But +1

Answer (score 1):

The system independent way is using PHP_EOL constant.

New lines is not browser dependent, outer a tag with CSS [white-space:pre](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) you must to execute [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) php function to convert newlines to BR tags.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is browser independent, `\n` should be too.

Don't know about `\r`

MySQL won't convert it

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), this takes new line characters like you described and replaces them with a HTML line break (`<br />`).

Comment: Not really valid as an answer to the OP, but I am grateful for the info -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A big gotcha for me was that in single quoted strings `'like\nthis'` escape sequences (like `\n`) will not be interpreted.  You have to use double quotes `"like\nthis"` to get an actual newline.

Comment: That's what I'm talkin' about!

Comment: you said that when data comes from textarea newlines will be represented always with `\r\n`: are you sure that ALL browser will send data as you said?